# Comunication between an Electron App and another platform app

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, reactjs, electron

Is it possible to create an Electron app, loaded from a React JS, to edit an image sent by another application?

E.g:

- A C# or Java application calls the Electron JS app, passing an imagem to it.
- The Electron JS make modifications on Image and then send it back to C# or Java application

How could I do something like that?